# Adding two parameters cause a NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-urls

I have created a model for a logbook :

```
class LogBook(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

class LogMessage(models.Model):
    logbook = models.ForeignKey(
        LogBook, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="logmessages")
    message = models.CharField()
```

**My view**

```
def logmessage_delete(request, logmessage_id, log_id, token):
    log = get_object_or_404(LogBook, token=token,  pk=log_id)
    logmessages = LogMessage.objects.filter(logbook=log, message=logmessage_id)
    logmessages.delete()
```

**Url**

```
delete/<int:logmessage_id>/<int:log_id>/<str:token>
```

In my template I tried :

```
 {% url 'log-delete' logmessage_id log_id token %}
```

I get a no reverse match but if I tried for example : http://localhost:8000/log/delete/15/9/1 it working just fine.

full error :

> Reverse for 'log-delete' with arguments '('', '', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['log/delete/(?P<logmessage_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<log_id>[0-9]+)/(?P[^/]+)$']

Any idea ?

Comment: Show us the full error message including the patterns tried and the full url mapping.

Comment: The `logmessage_id`, `log_id` and `token` variable apparently do not exist in the template.

Comment: @KlausD I've updated my post, thanks !

Comment: Yep, your variables are not filled.

Comment: @KlausD what does that mean, I have added them to my URL and in my template

Comment: @J.DOE can you show us the render function that renders delete form i.e the function that render template containing '{% url 'log-delete' logmessage_id log_id token %}'

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
{% abs_url 'app_name:log-delete' request logmessage_id=logmessage_id log_id=log_id token=token %}
```

Here we use **abs_url** (template tag) and **app_name** is the name of the app.The abs_url template tag code is shown in below.This code is 100% Working.

```
from django import template
from django.urls import reverse
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def abs_url(value, request, **kwargs):
    return reverse(value,kwargs=kwargs)
```